# Laravel to MySQL Query Connection Timing Logging

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm stuck trying to clear up lag and timing issues with my Laravel site and was curious if there was a way to check the timing of connections between the host the Laravel site and its MySQL database's host.

I'm trying to eliminate possibilities of where lag comes in and I want to make sure the two being on separate hosts (though in the same local network) isn't the issue.

Comment: @DileepaNipunSalinda: please do not make edits to apply code formatting to proper nouns. Software products like Laravel, MySQL and so forth are not themselves code. Just get the case right (usually an initial cap, sometimes a camel cap, and all-caps for acronyms). Code formatting can be use for code, config, and general I/O.

Comment: @halfer ok. thanks for mention it for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel is implemented in PHP, you can do something like so.

```
$TimeQuerySent = microtime(true) ;
// Send Request
$TimeQueryReturned = microtime(true) ;
$TimeConsumed = $TimeQueryReturned - $TimeQuerySent ;
```

The foregoing takes advantage of the fact that calling **microtime** in this manner cause it to return a floating point number. Since time progresses forward, $TimeQueryReturned is always greater than $TimeQuerySent, and the microsecond precision should be adequate if there is more than a fleeting lag on the connection.

Of course, the above measures only the overall time consumed by the request, which includes time spent by the server executing the query.

Getting information from the server side can be achieved by adding something like the following to your query.

```
declare StartTime FLOAT;    
set StartTime=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP(6));
select starttime,....
```

When the first statement is the very first statement in your stored routine or dynamically generated SQL statement, **StartTime** returns the time when the query began executing on the server, which is about as close as you can get to precisely when the MySQL engine started working on it. Requesting **UTC_TIMESTAMP(6)** causes the timestamp to be returned to the nearest microsecond, and implicitly casts it to float, while wrapping the **UNIX_TIMESTAMP** function around it converts the returned timestamp to a Unix timestamp. Since all three values are floating point Unix timestamps, you can compare all three times to put a finer point on whether the delay is a network lag or a query execution lag.

Answer (score 0):

This can help [Laravel Debugbar (Integrates PHP Debug Bar)](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)